# Paginated datatable doesn't show any records in next page

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable, spring-security

I have a datatable with pagination: with `rows = 7` the first 7 items are correctly loaded and displayed; But when we click the links to see the next set of elements then "no record found" is displayed.

For the table footer template, we have used

```
     In total there are #{fn:length(deviceBean.devices)} devices.
```

which shows us (11 items found) that in all their are more items to be shown

What am I doing wrong ?

Here the xhtml file code:

```
    <f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

    <h:head />


    <h:form>
        <p:growl id="messages">
            <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                <p:commandButton type="button" value="Summary" />
                <p:separator />
            </p:toolbarGroup>
        </p:growl>
    </h:form>

    <h:form>



        <p:dataTable id="tbl1" var="searchvalue"
            value="#{searchBean.searchmodel}" rows="1">
            <p:column>

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Search Criteria" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="By State Name" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Search Input" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{searchvalue.criteria}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Selected Model" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{searchvalue.model}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Start date" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{searchvalue.startdate}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="End date" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{searchvalue.enddate}" />
            </p:column>
            <!-- <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Age Range" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{searchvalue.agerange}" />
            </p:column> -->

        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
<p:spacer width="100" height="10" /> and <p:spacer width="20" height="20" />
<h:outputText value="&#160;" />
    <h:form>

        <h:form>
            <p:growl id="messages">
                <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                    <p:commandButton type="button" value="Detail:" />
                    <p:separator />
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:growl>
        </h:form>

        <p:dataTable id="tbl" var="device" value="#{deviceBean.devices}"
            paginator="true" rows="7">
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Name" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{device.name}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Email" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{device.email}" />
            </p:column>


            <f:facet name="footer">  
            In total there are #{fn:length(deviceBean.devices)} devices.  
          </f:facet>

        </p:dataTable>

        <br />


    </h:form>

</f:view>
```

here is the managed bean class:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SearchBean implements Serializable {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest());
    private List<SearchModel> searchmodel = (List) request.getAttribute("search_attributes");

    public List<SearchModel> getSearchmodel() {
        return searchmodel;
    }

}
```

@BalusC :no i haven't used any thing beyond spring security, I am not managing beans by Spring, I can explain how it works :  After security authentication from Spring security the control comes to welcom.jsp page, in this page  I have used `<jsp:forward page="/faces/index.xhtml"></jsp:forward` , which is my form , when form is submitted I call a class with form data in it , this class (Showsummary.java) does data query and puts data in key value pair like this req.setAttribute("search_attributes", searchattributes); , and then control comes to my managed bean again which returns "success" and this is mapped to the xhtml file which I have shown above in my faces-config, managed bean of summary.xhtml whose code i have written above access the data in this way :

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest());
    private List<SearchModel> searchmodel = (List) request.getAttribute("search_attributes");

    public List<SearchModel> getSearchmodel() {
        return searchmodel;
    }
```

Comment: For starters, you're doing wrong by not showing any code here, not telling us what version of primefaces you're using etc. No one will be able to help you without any of that info

Comment: Is there no one who can help me out

Comment: Hi there. While there is nothing obviously wrong with what you've posted here, the problem will lie mostly within your custom data model. What does `searchModel` implement? Add some debugging lines in the load method to show that rows are actually being returned during the paging operation

Comment: I called my DAO from summary managed bean and redesigned my managed bean it , its working now, thanks :)